# How to get model.summary when model is under defien function and used 'self'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am not comfortable with `self` class used in python. I am using following code (which i got from internet resources)  in `keras` library. In this code for parameter declaration is done with the help of `self`. How to get answer for `model.summary()` for `build_generator` in following code.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout, multiply
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Embedding, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
class CGAN():
    def __init__(self,width=50, height=50, channels=1):
        # Input shape
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.img_rows = 50
        self.img_cols = 50
        self.channels = 1
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
        self.num_classes = 10
        self.latent_dim = 100

        optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        # Build and compile the discriminator
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['accuracy'])

        # Build the generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        # The generator takes noise and the target label as input
        # and generates the corresponding digit of that label
        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape=(1,))
        img = self.generator([noise, label])

        # For the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        # The discriminator takes generated image as input and determines validity
        # and the label of that image
        valid = self.discriminator([img, label])

        # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator)
        # Trains generator to fool discriminator
        self.combined = Model([noise, label], valid)
        self.combined.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
            optimizer=optimizer)

    def build_generator(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=self.latent_dim))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Dense(512))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Dense(np.prod(self.img_shape), activation='tanh'))
        model.add(Reshape(self.img_shape))

        model.summary()

        noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        label = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
        label_embedding = Flatten()(Embedding(self.num_classes, self.latent_dim)(label))

        model_input = multiply([noise, label_embedding])
        img = model(model_input)

        return Model([noise, label], img)
```

Comment: self is a keyword used for attributes and methods of a class. After you define the class, you can instantiate an object. When the object is instantiated you can call one of its methods using the dot notation like: myObject.build_generator()

Comment: great, i just write `Z=CGAN()` and i got the summary. (However in above code build_discriminator is not mentioned, which is my mistake, but i have code for it, and i got the answer) Thnx.